# How to create a PNG strip from a Photoshop timeline

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, gif

I'm looking to make transparent GIF-like animations for webpages. However, saving transparent GIFs for webpages causes all sorts of problems - the most prominent being a white halo. If I can save all of the frames as a PNG strip, I can have the js run the animation and avoid any problems. My question pertains to the fact that I don't know how to generate these strips.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to generate: http://darsa.in/motio/img/ash_crimson_kiss.gif

I know I can save it as a GIF and then use other software to generate the strip. However, saving it as a GIF produces the transparency problems so I'm trying to save it as a strip directly.

Is there a way to save a timeline in Photoshop into a PNG strip?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to use Export > Render Video...

[image]

Select "Photoshop image Sequence" and the format to "PNG".

Then in order to produce a Sprite Sheet I think your best option is to use something in the likes of the [HTML5-Photoshop-Sprite-Sheet-Creator](https://github.com/williammalone/HTML5-Photoshop-Sprite-Sheet-Creator) and produce your sprite sheet via a Photoshop Script.

You could also produce a compound Script that merges the two processes into a single task!

Hope you can do it!